# opencl device missing

Tags: ati, devices, opencl

I am using latest catalyst drivers from amd (Kubuntu 13.04).
Previously(say one month ago) am using OpenCL 1.2 for my PyOpenCL worked great with three computing devices
1. Turks
2. Devastater
3. AuthenticAMD

but recently it is showing only Two computing  devices (same driver). I checked with clinfo and AMD_codeXL

1. Devastater
2. AuthenticAMD

How can i bring back the third computing device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magically after patch (http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?82948-AMD-Catalyst-13-8-Beta-Driver-For-Linux-Released&p=348554#post348554) and reinstalling the driver fixed the issue.